# Swift: How to automatically generate corresponding enum when use Codable

Tags: swift, generics, codable

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String
    var createdAt: Date
    var updatedAt: Date
    var githubId: Int
}

extension User {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.createdAt = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .createdAt)
        self.updatedAt = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .updatedAt)
        self.githubId = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .githubId)
    }
}
```

when I called  `container.decode`, the key is like a enum, which name corresponds to the property name, how to implement this feature.

Comment: Swift already does this for you. You can delete you extension.

Comment: You can get Codable conformance for your type for free if its properties are also conforming to Codable. The CodingKeys subtype used to map keys of the archived object data to the properties of your type is also generated for free in this case.